# How to work with text properly in TextView/TextArea tview golang

Tags: go

So i'm using this tview library. Have a TextView. Try to put a text inside - it sets properly, but
[image: looks good]
This one is good.

But if i keep scrolling - it will go into a an endless void. I want to prevent that from happening
[image: going nowhere]
[image: the VOOOOOID]
Looked through the docs - only thing i could think of is maxlines, but i guess it's no use. Asking for help.